# Why when I run a method with multiple threads is slower?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I run this with one thread.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(x => beginAnalysis("C:\\Images\\1"));
        thread.Start();
    }

    public static void beginAnalysis(string folderPath)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var imagesPath = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        var sealSaver = new ImageProcessingLib.SealSaver();

        foreach (string imagePath in imagesPath)
        {
            sealSaver.SealSaver(imagePath);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}",sw.Elapsed.ToString());Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The result of time is

Total time: 00:00:09.0007113

but when I run four threads time is very different

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(x => beginAnalysis("C:\\Images\\1"));
        thread.Start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(x => beginAnalysis("C:\\Images\\2"));
        thread2.Start();
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(x => beginAnalysis("C:\\Images\\3"));
        thread3.Start();
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(x => beginAnalysis("C:\\Images\\4"));
        thread4.Start();
    }

    public static void beginAnalysis(string folderPath)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var imagesPath = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        var sealSaver = new ImageProcessingLib.SealSaver();

        foreach (string imagePath in imagesPath)
        {
            sealSaver.SealSaver(imagePath);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}",sw.Elapsed.ToString());Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The result of time is

```
Total time: 00:00:12.0002174

Total time: 00:00:11.0006616

Total time: 00:00:12.0011639

Total time: 00:00:13.0006828
```

Why does the time change if it is the same folder?

These are the characteristics of my computer:

operating system : Windows 8.1 Pro  - 64 Bit

RAM : 6 GB

Processor: Intel i5-34170 3.20 Ghz  Cores - 4

Cache L1 256KB - L2 1.0 MB - L3 6.0 MB

I develop with framework 4.0 and visual studio 2010

The library "ImageProcessingLib" does not use shared resources.

Why does time change if it is the same folder?

Comment: Parallelization isn't automatically faster than single thread; especially not if you accessing a single resource like a single disk, then you'll queue up quite a lot of disk queues etc.

Comment: Depending on what size those images are, and what SealSaver does, this might be I/O bound - in which case running more threads will just make them fight for disk access.

Comment: Your second (slow) example is using four separate "images" folders.  Are they all the same?

Comment: "More threads != faster". You're just utilizing the CPU better if you have more cores. In this scenario you're just multiplying the total amount of work to be done and assigning it to a bunch of threads, which now get CPU time less frequently.

Comment: You did get 4 times the workload done, even if it took a couple of seconds more. The bottleneck here could be the disk for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your code can run slower in an MT enviroment:

- Running code multithreaded adds management overhead compared to running single threaded. Normally you'd hope that the parallelization of the executed code will make up for it in the sense that the overall execution time goes down on a multi-core system at the possible expense of every thread taking the same time or a little longer if/when you manage to light up all cores.
- You're code is doing something that is essential a serial operation (scanning the directory) in parallel. If you're hitting the same directory, the results are very likely cached by your OS, but you're hitting up four directories. This means you'll have to wait for the IO to finish for each one of them while the operations fall over each other. That's not a good scenario for improved performance.

Running code multithreaded for performance reasons (as opposed to, say, running code multithreaded because you want your UI to be responsive at all times) only makes sense if there is no common choke point and the operations are completely independent. That's not the case in your example, because the IO is the bottleneck and that can't be efficiently parallelized on a normal computer because you're dealing with disk latency. There are ways to improve the latency (faster disks or SSDs) but you're still dealing with an operation that's essentially serial.